# How does PHP determine whether a variable is an array or a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm confused as to how PHP determines whether a variable is a string or an array. It seems to depend on the operators being used.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$z1 = "abc";
$out = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($z1); $i++)
{
    // $out[$i] = $z1[$i]; 
    $out = $out.$z1[$i];
}
print $out;
?>
```

In the above version `$out` becomes a string (`print $z1` shows "abc"). However, if I use the first line `$out[$i] = $z1[$i];`, `$out` becomes an array.

Can someone please clarify why this happens, and if its possible to access a string's characters with square brackets without converting the output to an array?

Comment: Interestingly, if you initialise `$out` as a non-empty string, e.g. `$out = 'a'`, it stays a string...

Comment: From the PHP Manual: [String access and modification by character](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). As a more general note, the PHP Manual is quite good: you should take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a string in PHP is considered a set of data writen in linear format (i.e: `$var = "username=SmokeyBear05,B-day=01/01/1980";`)

An array however is a set of data broken down into several parts. A sort of list format if you will. As an example I've written the data string from before, into an array format...

```
Array(['username']=>"SmokeyBear05", ['B-day']=>"01/01/1980")
```

Now strings are generally defined as such: $var="Your String";
Arrays however can be written in three different formats:

```
$var1 = array('data1','data2','data3');
$var2 = array('part A'=>'data1','part B'=>'data2','part C'=>'data3');
```

The output of var1 starts the index value at 0. The output of var2 however, sets a custom index value. Now the third way to write an array (least common format) is as such:

```
$var[0]="data1";
$var[1]="data2";
$var[2]="data3";
```

This takes more work, but allows you to set the index.

Most web developers working with PHP will set data from an external source as a string to deliver it to another PHP script, and then break it down into an array using the explode() function.

Answer (score 0):

When you define variable `$out = ""`, `for` loop doesn't understand this variable as string value. If you set `$out[$i]` value, by default, it was treated as an array.

If you want to get the output result as string value, you can define `$out = "a"` to make sure it's a string variable.

Comment: While this appears to be the answer, it'd be interesting why PHP doesn't treat the string `""` as a string but does `"a"`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So how do I define an empty string?. Based on the replies here, writing $out="" will create an array.

Comment: @user51726 It doesn't seem to be possible in your case. If you hate the `a` string, try with a white space `$out=' '`.